# Why am I getting a run time error 2185 on a form and not on another?

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error, keyup

I'm kinda new to MS Access and I'm sort of learning while coding, so forgive me if my question is a bit weird.

I have created a form based on a table, and in the form I have a text box that the user would type something and it should filter the table and show the results based on what the user typed. There are two forms with pretty much the same code on them (named Rec and Cx). In one of them (Rec) the above description works just fine, but the other (Cx) don't and I get a run-time error 2185. Let me show you some code:

```
Private Sub strConsRecDesc_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

FiltroRec = ""
FilterTextDesc = ""
If Len("" & Me.strConsRecDesc.Text) > 0 Then
    intLenDesc = Len(Me.strConsRecDesc.Text)
    RequeryForm
    strConsRecDesc.SetFocus
    Me.FilterOn = True
    If intLenDesc > Len(Me.strConsRecDesc.Text) Then
        Me.strConsRecDesc = Me.strConsRecDesc & " "
    Else
        Me.strConsRecDesc = FilterTextDesc
    End If
    strConsRecDesc.SelStart = intLenDesc
Else
    RequeryForm
    strConsRecDesc.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

I heard it is good practice to lable variables and fields based on data type, so here *int* stands for integer, *str* for strings and *Desc* refers to the **Description** field.

Based on what is typed in the field *strConsRecDesc* I filter the table using the **RequeryForm** in there, that basically checks all the fields in the form that the user can write into. Let me show you the part for the description field:

```
strConsRecDesc.SetFocus
If Len(strConsRecDesc.Value) > 0 Then
    FilterTextDesc = Me!strConsRecDesc.Value
    If Len(FiltroRec) > 0 Then
        FiltroRec = FiltroRec & " And "
    End If
    FiltroRec = FiltroRec & "[recDescricao] LIKE '*" & FilterTextDesc & "*'"
End If
```

In this form (Rec), I can write, i.e. *this is a test* and no record is shown, because there is no record with *this is a test* written in it, and that is correct. If I type something that matches the criteria it works just fine.
However, in the other form (the Cx one), I have the following code for KeyUp:

```
Private Sub strConsCxDesc_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

FiltroCx = ""
FilterTextDesc = ""
If Len("" & Me.strConsCxDesc.Text) > 0 Then
    intLenDesc = Len(Me.strConsCxDesc.Text)
    RequeryForm
    strConsCxDesc.SetFocus
    Me.FilterOn = True
    If intLenDesc > Len(Me.strConsCxDesc.Text) Then
        Me.strConsCxDesc = Me.strConsCxDesc & " "
    Else
        Me.strConsCxDesc = FilterTextDesc
    End If
    strConsCxDesc.SelStart = intLenDesc
Else
    RequeryForm
    strConsCxDesc.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

And the equivalent RequeryForm for the Cx is:

```
    strConsCxDesc.SetFocus
    If Len(strConsCxDesc.Value) > 0 Then
        FilterTextDesc = Me!strConsCxDesc.Value
        If Len(FiltroCx) > 0 Then
            FiltroCx = FiltroCx & " And "
        End If
        FiltroCx = FiltroCx & "[cxDescricao] LIKE '*" & FilterTextDesc & "*'"
    End If
```

But in the Cx one if I type *this is a test* in the *strConsCxDesc* textbox I get a run-time error 2185.

I understand that with just this bit of code it is kinda hard to grasp what I'm trying to do, but I really don't know why I'm getting this error if the code is the same.

I appreciate any help, and I'm sorry for my bad english, it's not my mother language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the exact error message? What line triggers the error? Have you step debugged? I have never used any of the Key events for this - why are you? Why not textbox AfterUpdate?

Comment: You should be using the `Change()` event of the textbox.

Comment: @June7 I'm using the KeyUp so it triggers after the user releases any key while the focus still in the box. If I use the AfterUpdate it is required that the user "leaves" the specific text box (by hitting Enter or clicking somewhere else). The exact error message is that I can only refer to a property or method if the command has focus. The error triggers in the If loop, that checks if there's anything written in the box. I have step debugged and in the Rec one it works just fine, just this Cx that's acting weird. :(

Comment: @KostasK. I'll try to switch and try that. I'll report back sometime soon. The ```Change()``` will also trigger after the user types anything, right? I mean, it does not require the user to leave the field, or does it?

Comment: The `Change()` event fires while the textbox has focus and it's text is being changed (while typing). You can capture the content with the `.Text` property of the control. Once the control looses the focus, the contents of the `Text` property is copied over to the `Value` property.

Comment: @KostasK. I tried to use the ```Change()``` event but it is still triggering the error. Sometimes it trigger in the first ```If``` loop, and sometimes in the second. Apparently the reason is that it is losing the focus somehow, even if I enforce the focus with ```.SetFocus``` in the line above the loops. I tried to remove the ```.SetFocus``` but it still doesn't work. I don't get why the Rec Form is working and the Cx Form is not. I'm so confused... what am I missing? Am I very stupid and typed something wrong? :(((

Comment: @KostasK. @June7 I have an update. After trying to brute-force the solution, I started to compare every single part of the forms. The difference between them was a property. Well, two properties, actually. In the Rec one, I had the ```AllowAddition``` and ```AllowDeletion``` properties set to True and in the other form they were set to false. I don't know why this interferes, but after changing them to True on the Cx one, it worked perfectly... I think the *why* requires a very deep knowledge of the software, but I really wonder why that property would stop my code... Thanks anyway.